# Cannot show filter

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, custom

hello i've a problem when i want to add some filter to my product ..
i've create attribute to filter, add to attribute set. But on frontend not show anything. But the filter show on 'sort by' selection. I want to add custom filter beside 'sort by' selection. Can someone help me ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should work with your current configuration.

My guess is, because you have chosen Simple Product only, and in your category there are not simple items matching with it which is why it's not showing up.

You can go ahead and select all products type in "Apply To" section.

**Then make sure a product is assigned to it as `YES`.**

**If you don't want it to be in sortable option**

Just set `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` to `NO`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: still not working, but when i add to 'default' attribute set, on manage product the option to select the 'size type' not showing :(

Comment: First, this attribute should be assigned to your Attribute group, then go to product of that group and select "size type" and it should show up in category that holds this product.